# For a continuous function $f$ and $f''(x)\geq 0$ $\forall x\in [0,2\pi]$. Show that: $\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)\cdot\cos(x)\cdot dx\geq 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

**Original Question:** Let $f$ be a continuous function, whose first and second derivatives are continuous on $[0,2\pi]$ and $f''(x)\geq 0$ $\forall x\in [0,2\pi]$. Show that: $$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)\cdot\cos(x)\cdot dx\geq 0$$ I have failed to develop a proof for the above proposition, but I have some intuition to believe why it should be true.

**My intuition:** $f''(x)\geq 0$ $\forall x\in [0,2\pi]$ means that $f'(x)$ is increasing on $[0,2\pi]$, which in turn means that $f(x)$ is increasing on this interval. Thus, $f(a)\leq f(b)\leq f(c)$ for $a\in [0,\pi/2),b\in[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$ and $c\in (3\pi/2,2\pi]$, respectively. For notational convenience, let $A=[0,\pi/2),B=[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$ and $C=(3\pi/2,2\pi]$. It can be easily proven that $\cos(x)> 0$ on $A$ and $C$, while $\cos(x)\leq 0$ on $B$. The above integral $I$ can be restated as: $$I=I_A+I_B+I_C$$ where $$I_A=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}f(x)\cdot\cos(x)\cdot dx\;,I_B=\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}f(x)\cdot\cos(x)\cdot dx\text{ and }\;I_C=\int_{3\pi/2}^{2\pi}f(x)\cdot\cos(x)\cdot dx$$ I considered the case $f(x)\leq 0$ to be an obstacle, which I found removed when I realised by graphing the functions $x^4\cdot\cos(x)$ and $(x^4-15000)\cdot\cos(x)$ on $[0,2\pi]$: Scaling the graph by a constant factor does not alter the integral, since $\int_{0}^{2\pi}k\cos(x)\cdot dx=0$ for all constant $k$. Thus, without any loss of generality it can be assumed that $f(x)\geq 0$ $\forall x\in [0,2\pi]$. What I have so far is:

1. $f(x)\geq 0$ is an increasing function on $[0,2\pi]$
2. $I_A$ and $I_C$ make positive contributions to $I$, with the contribution of $I_C$ being substantially larger because $f$ is an increasing function. To the contrary, $I_B$ makes a substantial negative contribution.

What remains unresolved for me even intuitively is how $I_C+I_A\geq I_B$. I'm stuck at this point and have no idea how to proceed. Thus, **I would like to know why $I_C+I_A\geq I_B$**. Any other hints in the direction of producing a rigorous proof would also be appreciated.

Comment: Just because the derivative is increasing doesn't mean the original function is.

Comment: @PeterForeman ...and my entire intuition destroyed in seconds :)

Comment: @PeterForeman Can you provide a counter-example, though?

Comment: Have you tried just integrating by parts?

Comment: @ΜάρκοςΚαραμέρης Not yet. I'll try that.

Comment: For a counterexample take $(x-\pi/2)^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integrate by parts twice to get that

$$\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\cos(x)\:dx = f'(2\pi)-f'(0)-\int_0^{2\pi}f''(x)\cos(x)\:dx$$

Then making the integrand as large as possible we have that

$$f'(2\pi)-f'(0)-\int_0^{2\pi}f''(x)\cos(x)\:dx \geq f'(2\pi)-f'(0) - \int_0^{2\pi}f''(x)\:dx$$

$$= f'(2\pi)-f'(0) -(f'(2\pi)-f'(0)) = 0$$

which is true because $f''(x)$ is nonnegative.

Comment: Or just note that the RHS is exactly$$\int_0^{2\pi}f''(x)(1-\cos{(x)})\,\mathrm{d}x\ge0$$because we are integrating a positive continuous function.

Comment: @PeterForeman I like this one too!

Answer (score 2):

Another way way:

Integration by parts gives
$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x) \cos x dx=f(x) \sin x|_{0}^{2\pi} -\int_{0}^{2\pi} f'(x) \sin x dx$$
Next use $$\int_{0}^{2a} g(x) dx= \int_{0}^{a}[g(x)+g(2a-x)] dx$$
$$\implies I=-\int_{0}^{\pi} [f'(x)-f'(2\pi-x)] \sin x dx~~~(1)$$
AS $f''(x)\ge 0 \implies f'(x)>0$ is an increasing function.

Consider $x\in [0,\pi] \implies x \le 2\pi-x \implies f'(x) \le f'(2\pi-x) \implies f'(x)-f'(2\pi-x) \le 0 $. $\sin x$ being positive in $[0.\pi]$, from (1) it follows that
$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x) \cos x dx \ge 0$$